# smoothing out data so plotting using matplotlib and FFT data looks nicer ( frequency spectrum )

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, fft, pyaudio

basically i have the fundamentals of a music visualiser however i would like to improve it,at the moment im getting lots of data and plotting the absolute value of my fft calculations, however this looks very messy and i would like it to be smoothed out somewhat, i will post a gif of what its like below. i would the data to be smoothed out so there is less spikes in noise, and to remove the odd values being plotted at 0 on the x axis and really high up on the y axis as it happens whenever theres noise at all, it also goes off the graph which i dont like.

gif of example : https://i.imgur.com/eOGzPFd.gifv

video of smoothed visualiser: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C2TV2DaCVk0

is it smoothed just because its seperated and plotted as bars? because that is my eventual goal, is to seperate the data into bars and plot it like that. i also prefer being able to see more of a variation in the graph when music is going up in low frequencies, however testing a range of low frequencies on my graph, it doesnt seem to show the difference.

i appreciate all the help anyone has given me previously and anyone who continues to help me!!! <3

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style

pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
audio_data = 0
callback_output = []

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, flag):
    global audio_data
    audio_data = np.fromstring(in_data, dtype=np.float32)
    callback_output.append(audio_data)
    return None,pyaudio.paContinue


stream = pa.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                 channels=1,
                 rate=44100,
                 output=False,
                 input=True,
                 stream_callback=callback)

stream.start_stream()

plt.ion() # Stop matplotlib windows from blocking

# Setup figure, axis and initiate plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ln, = ax.plot([], [], 'b,:')

x = 0

while stream.is_active():

    fft_data = np.fft.fft(audio_data)
    fft_freq = np.fft.fftfreq(len(fft_data),d=1/44100)

    ln.set_xdata(np.abs(fft_freq))
    ln.set_ydata(np.abs((fft_data)))


    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()

    if x == 0:
        ax.relim()
        ax.autoscale_view()
        ax.set_xlim([-500,15000])
        ax.set_ylim([0,5])
        x=1

stream.close()
pa.terminate()
```

Comment: suggest log/log or semilogy.  If you want to smooth in frequency space, you can do that (use np.convolve), or you can smooth by windowing your data and averaging the fft**2.  Suggest you use `scipy.signal.welch` and choose nfft = Ndata / 4 (or 8).

Comment: will try that tomorrow thankyou!